# How to get the location of a VM on Hyper-V server using powershell

Tags: powershell, hyper-v

My Hyper-V server has vms divided in different logical drives. E.g.: D drive of server contains 4 vms, E drive contains 3 vms.

1. I know the name of the drive on Hyper-V server (ex: D:), how can i get the names of the virtual machines in that drive.
2. I know the name of the virtual machine on Hyper-V server, how can i get the drive on Hyper-V server in which the virtual machines is present.

Regards,
Abhishek

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look to this script:

http://jackiechen.org/2011/10/26/powershell-list-the-hyper-v-vm-vhd-location/